# Django model class self-representation

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Is there a handy way to create a `json` self-representation of a model Class in Django project?

Say I have a model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    some_bool_field = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    some_char_field = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
```

I need a serializer of some sort that will return me a json object representing model architecture of the class itself, something like:

```
{ 
  'model_class': 'MyModel',
  'some_bool_field': 
     {'type': 'BooleanField', 'default': 'true'},
  'some_char_field': 
     {'type': 'CharField', 'max_length': '20', 'blank': 'false' }
}
```

I'm using `Django-rest-framework` for `API` creation, so maybe there is ready solution buried inside framework I'm not aware of?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to 'workaround' technical documentation for api, instead I want to create separate endpoint that will return list of available endpoints and/or which endpoint is expecting which data and in which format.

Comment: @pycoder Rest-framework will return fields that are required if something's missing in 'POST' request, but it does not notify about fields that are not mandatory.

Comment: I'm not completely sure but I'd look into the [`_meta` API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/meta/).

Comment: @pycoder this might actually work, although I'll have to write serializer from zero, but at least with meta API I now know how to access field properties, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not good to expose your database tables via APIs, specially when there are some models or fields certain types of users shouldn't have access. Instead you could expose the serializers used in your API endpoints using some API-explorer or docs generator integrated with Django REST Framework (DRF).

There's a full page in DRF docs with options on how to document your API: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/. I've already used [Django REST Swagger](https://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and it is pretty straight forward and well integrated with DRF, but there's plenty of options in that page. You should really consider trying one of these alternatives.